# How to fill a Form Field with data from Google Analytics with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I wish to insert "Session Duration" and "Pages / Session" from Google Analytics into form fields, so the data is submitted to the back end.

I'm able to enter values using URL parameters or by manually specifying values in the form script, but I wish for the data to be captured automatically based on the browser's cookie. I cannot find any documentation anywhere and I don't know where else to look for it.

The result should be: I'm browsing the website for 3 minutes and clicking through 5 pages. I end up on a page where I can submit a form for a contest. The form contains two hidden fields: Session Duration and Pages per Session. Automatically, Session Duration should be filled with 3 and Pages per Session should be filled with 5, thanks to the Google Analytics cookie. Then I submit the form and the data from both fields are submitted along with the form and mapped with fields on the other end (in this case a CRM, creating those fields is not a problem).

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, Google Analytics uses the Client ID to stitch these sessions and page views together after the data has been collected not within the cookies themselves. Therefore this data would not be available in the cookies.

You would need to add your own cookies to the website and get the data from these cookies you create to get this data.